# print associative array in TCL like Dumper prints in Perl

Tags: tcl

**-----------------------------Perl Code-----------------------------**

```
        use Data::Dumper;
        my %hash = ('abc' => 123, 'def' => 6);
        print Dumper(\%hash);
```

gives output like,

```
    $VAR1 = {
              'def' => 6
              'abc' => 123
            };
```

**-----------------------------TCL Code-----------------------------**

```
    set hash(abc) 123
    set hash(def) 6
```

I want to print this associative array like the perl prints. Is there any way to print this in TCL other than `parray hash` ?

Comment: `parray` is not a command, but a `proc`. Do `info body parray`. You have the code in your hand. Customize it as per your idea.

Comment: @Dinesh What do you mean that `parray` is not a command? `proc` is used to make commands, so if `parray` was created through `proc`, is it not a command?

Comment: @Jerry : Agreed with you. What I meant to say is that `parray` is not a built-in command like `lindex`, but a procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about producing an executable script that will create an array, do this:

```
proc dumpArray {arrayName} {
    upvar $arrayName ary
    return [list array set $arrayName [array get ary]]
}
```

If you want the output to be multiline and somewhat readable, you need to do some more work:

```
proc dumpArray {arrayName} {
    upvar $arrayName ary
    set result [list array set $arrayName]
    append result "{\n"
    foreach key [lsort -dictionary [array names ary]] {
        append result "    " [list $key $ary($key)] "\n"
    }
    append result "}"
    return $result
}
```

As you can see from the simplicity of the first version, we wouldn't normally bother with writing a specific piece of code to dump an array; it's effectively a one-liner in the first place.

---

With one of these in place, you'd then do:

```
array set hash {"abc" 123 "def" 6}
puts [dumpArray hash]
```